# How to get missing point values in stat data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, statistics

I am writing a stats reporting and I am working with a ton of data so we are only getting pieces. For instance we are outputting DateTime/Data objects and tracking in interval of months from the start date to the end date.

The problem is the data only puts out months that have data in there, for instance it would only give December 2010 February 2011 and August 2011. I need to know how I would construct it so I could put 0s where January 2011, March 2011, etc.. are.

Can someone give me an idea of how I would construct this without a lot of overhead? I was thinking of first getting a loop, then getting the necessary interval (e.g. Minutes, Months, Years) and putting that into a list, then when I go through my DateTime/Data objects checking if its greater than 0 replace that. Also this is for creating points on a chart.

Comment: From where are you getting data? Database? Web service? Some other data source?

Comment: Data is coming from the database from a Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your data into a linked list, and insert missing datapoints:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Whatever
{
  public struct DataPoint
  {
    private DateTime time;
    private int value;

    public DataPoint(DateTime time, int value)
    {
      this.time = time;
      this.value = value;
    }

    public DateTime Time
    {
      get { return this.time; }
    }

    public int Value
    {
      get { return this.value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
      return string.Format("{0:D2}/{1}: {2}", this.time.Month, this.time.Year, this.value);
    }
  }

  public static class Program
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
      // List of the datapoints, e.g. loaded from a database
      var dataPoints = new List<DataPoint>();
      dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(new DateTime(2010, 11, 1), 10));
      dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(new DateTime(2011,  2, 1), 20));
      dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(new DateTime(2011,  3, 1), 30));
      dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(new DateTime(2011,  6, 1), 40));
      dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(new DateTime(2011,  9, 1), 50));
      dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(new DateTime(2011, 12, 1), 60));
      dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(new DateTime(2012,  2, 1), 70));

      // Endpoints of the measurement interval
      var begin = new DateTime(2010, 9, 1);
      var end   = new DateTime(2012, 4, 1);

      // Check each month and insert missing datapoints
      var time = begin;
      var i = 0;
      while (time <= end)
      {
        if (i < dataPoints.Count)
        {
          if (time < dataPoints[i].Time)
          {
            var dataPoint = new DataPoint(time, 0);
            dataPoints.Insert(i, dataPoint);
          }
        }
        else
        {
          var dataPoint = new DataPoint(time, 0);
          dataPoints.Add(dataPoint);
        }
        ++i;
        time = time.AddMonths(1);
      }

      // Print list
      foreach (var dataPoint in dataPoints)
        Console.WriteLine(dataPoint);
    }
  } 
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you only need to plot these data, then there is no need to insert missing data points. I would simply interpolate between existing points, I mean, connect them. If the existing points are denoted by filled circles, then the missing points could be indicated by empty circles, sitting on these connecting lines (such a graph control can be written to plot points given by interpolation without storing them).

Comment: Hi, the chart is a line chart and the labels are months, what is missing is 0s for the months that there is no data for... could that be accomplished with interpolation? Thanks so much

Comment: PiRX's solution gives you a method to insert missing data points on database side. My solution inserts missing data points on client side.  My comment about the graph and interpolation refers to a situation when you are the developer of the graph control.

Comment: I see, yes your solution works better as it is a large set of data. Also if I wanted to change the interval to days how would I denote that? The measurements will be seconds, minutes, days, months, and years. Thank you so much for your help once again.

Comment: To use days instead of months, you should change AddMonths to AddDays. It is very important to round the timestamps: if you use months, then round every timestamp to months; and if you use days, then round every timestamp to days.

Comment: Thanks so much, this gave me the foundation and I was able to get it. You are awesome, thanks for helping a UI engineer out!

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible, I would advise to modify stored procedure and/or SQL call for this procedure and insert missing data with help of partial joins (LEFT/RIGHT JOIN) and COALESCE/ISNULL functions.

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @range AS TABLE (datePoint DATETIME);
DECLARE @data AS TABLE (datePoint DATETIME, value INT);

-- setup date range
DECLARE @currentDatePoint AS DATETIME;
SET @currentDatePoint = '01/01/2011'
WHILE @currentDatePoint < '01/01/2012'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @range VALUES (@currentDatePoint);
    SET @currentDatePoint = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @currentDatePoint);
END

-- setup test data
SET @currentDatePoint = '01/01/2011'
WHILE @currentDatePoint < '01/01/2012'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @data VALUES (@currentDatePoint, DATEPART(MONTH, @currentDatePoint));
    SET @currentDatePoint = DATEADD(MONTH, 2, @currentDatePoint);
END
--end setup

-- actual select
SELECT 
    r.datePoint, 
    ISNULL(d.value, 0) 
FROM 
    @range r
LEFT JOIN 
    @data d ON r.datePoint = d.datePoint
```